# In Android, how do I transform a FAB into a view, when a user scrolls down the fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-motionlayout

I want to have two buttons doing the same thing. One a FAB, and one a big plus sign that looks like a card.

[image: mockups][image]

Is it possible to have the FAB "explode" into the PlusSignView, maybe with a MotionLayout, when a user scrolls down to the bottom of the list?